# Miss from Cloudfront

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, devops, amazon-cloudfront

I always keep on receiving miss from CloudFront. This is my header. The header size is 12KB because of the large Content Security Policy Entries.
Can anybody help to fix this issue ?

```
HTTP/2 200
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 29 Apr 2019 07:44:55 GMT
server: nginx/1.15.9
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' http://*.facebook.com https://*.facebook.com http://*.fbcdn.net https://*.fbcdn.net http://connect.facebook.net https://connect.facebook.net http://*.googleusercontent.com https://*.googleusercontent.com http://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com http://assets.reactioncommerce.com https://assets.reactioncommerce.com http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com http://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com http://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.gstatic.com http://enginex.kadira.io https://enginex.kadira.io http://*.asort.com https://*.asort.com http://*.amazonaws.com https://*.amazonaws.com http://*.rtschannel.com https://*.rtschannel.com http://*.freshchat.com https://*.freshchat.com http://*.google.com https://*.google.com http://*.google.co.in https://*.google.co.in http://*.google-analytics.com https://*.google-analytics.com http://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect* https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect* http://*.youtube.com https://*.youtube.com http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js http://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js https://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js http://*.cloudfront.net https://*.cloudfront.net http://*.googletagmanager.com https://*.googletagmanager.com http://*.gstatic.com https://*.gstatic.com http://*.hotjar.com https://*.hotjar.com http://*.ytimg.com https://*.ytimg.com http://*.gravatar.com https://*.gravatar.com blob: http://*.razorpay.com https://*.razorpay.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://*.facebook.com https://*.facebook.com http://*.fbcdn.net https://*.fbcdn.net http://connect.facebook.net https://connect.facebook.net http://*.googleusercontent.com https://*.googleusercontent.com http://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com http://assets.reactioncommerce.com https://assets.reactioncommerce.com http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com http://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com http://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.gstatic.com http://enginex.kadira.io https://enginex.kadira.io http://*.asort.com https://*.asort.com http://*.amazonaws.com https://*.amazonaws.com http://*.rtschannel.com https://*.rtschannel.com http://*.freshchat.com https://*.freshchat.com http://*.google.com https://*.google.com http://*.google.co.in https://*.google.co.in http://*.google-analytics.com https://*.google-analytics.com http://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect* https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect* http://*.youtube.com https://*.youtube.com http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js http://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js https://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js http://*.cloudfront.net https://*.cloudfront.net http://*.googletagmanager.com https://*.googletagmanager.com http://*.gstatic.com https://*.gstatic.com http://*.hotjar.com https://*.hotjar.com http://*.ytimg.com https://*.ytimg.com http://*.gravatar.com https://*.gravatar.com blob: http://*.razorpay.com https://*.razorpay.com 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'self' ws://asort.com wss://asort.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.facebook.com http://*.fbcdn.net https://*.fbcdn.net http://connect.facebook.net https://connect.facebook.net http://*.googleusercontent.com https://*.googleusercontent.com http://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com http://assets.reactioncommerce.com https://assets.reactioncommerce.com http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com http://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com http://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.gstatic.com http://enginex.kadira.io https://enginex.kadira.io http://*.asort.com https://*.asort.com http://*.amazonaws.com https://*.amazonaws.com http://*.rtschannel.com https://*.rtschannel.com http://*.freshchat.com https://*.freshchat.com http://*.google.com https://*.google.com http://*.google.co.in https://*.google.co.in http://*.google-analytics.com https://*.google-analytics.com http://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect* https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect* http://*.youtube.com https://*.youtube.com http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js http://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js https://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js http://*.cloudfront.net https://*.cloudfront.net http://*.googletagmanager.com https://*.googletagmanager.com http://*.gstatic.com https://*.gstatic.com http://*.hotjar.com https://*.hotjar.com http://*.ytimg.com https://*.ytimg.com http://*.gravatar.com https://*.gravatar.com blob: http://*.razorpay.com https://*.razorpay.com; img-src data: 'self' http://*.facebook.com https://*.facebook.com http://*.fbcdn.net https://*.fbcdn.net http://connect.facebook.net https://connect.facebook.net http://*.googleusercontent.com https://*.googleusercontent.com http://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com http://assets.reactioncommerce.com https://assets.reactioncommerce.com http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com http://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com http://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.gstatic.com http://enginex.kadira.io https://enginex.kadira.io http://*.asort.com https://*.asort.com http://*.amazonaws.com https://*.amazonaws.com http://*.rtschannel.com https://*.rtschannel.com http://*.freshchat.com https://*.freshchat.com http://*.google.com https://*.google.com http://*.google.co.in https://*.google.co.in http://*.google-analytics.com https://*.google-analytics.com http://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect* https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect* http://*.youtube.com https://*.youtube.com http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js http://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js https://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js http://*.cloudfront.net https://*.cloudfront.net http://*.googletagmanager.com https://*.googletagmanager.com http://*.gstatic.com https://*.gstatic.com http://*.hotjar.com https://*.hotjar.com http://*.ytimg.com https://*.ytimg.com http://*.gravatar.com https://*.gravatar.com blob: http://*.razorpay.com https://*.razorpay.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://*.facebook.com https://*.facebook.com http://*.fbcdn.net https://*.fbcdn.net http://connect.facebook.net https://connect.facebook.net http://*.googleusercontent.com https://*.googleusercontent.com http://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com http://assets.reactioncommerce.com https://assets.reactioncommerce.com http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com http://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com http://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.gstatic.com http://enginex.kadira.io https://enginex.kadira.io http://*.asort.com https://*.asort.com http://*.amazonaws.com https://*.amazonaws.com http://*.rtschannel.com https://*.rtschannel.com http://*.freshchat.com https://*.freshchat.com http://*.google.com https://*.google.com http://*.google.co.in https://*.google.co.in http://*.google-analytics.com https://*.google-analytics.com http://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect* https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect* http://*.youtube.com https://*.youtube.com http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js http://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js https://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js http://*.cloudfront.net https://*.cloudfront.net http://*.googletagmanager.com https://*.googletagmanager.com http://*.gstatic.com https://*.gstatic.com http://*.hotjar.com https://*.hotjar.com http://*.ytimg.com https://*.ytimg.com http://*.gravatar.com https://*.gravatar.com blob: http://*.razorpay.com https://*.razorpay.com; font-src 'self' http://*.facebook.com https://*.facebook.com http://*.fbcdn.net https://*.fbcdn.net http://connect.facebook.net https://connect.facebook.net http://*.googleusercontent.com https://*.googleusercontent.com http://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com data: http://assets.reactioncommerce.com https://assets.reactioncommerce.com http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com http://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com http://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.gstatic.com http://enginex.kadira.io https://enginex.kadira.io http://*.asort.com https://*.asort.com http://*.amazonaws.com https://*.amazonaws.com http://*.rtschannel.com https://*.rtschannel.com http://*.freshchat.com https://*.freshchat.com http://*.google.com https://*.google.com http://*.google.co.in https://*.google.co.in http://*.google-analytics.com https://*.google-analytics.com http://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect* https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect* http://*.youtube.com https://*.youtube.com http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js http://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js https://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js http://*.cloudfront.net https://*.cloudfront.net http://*.googletagmanager.com https://*.googletagmanager.com http://*.gstatic.com https://*.gstatic.com http://*.hotjar.com https://*.hotjar.com http://*.ytimg.com https://*.ytimg.com http://*.gravatar.com https://*.gravatar.com blob: http://*.razorpay.com https://*.razorpay.com;
x-powered-by: Express
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-whom: rc-nginx
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
via: 1.1 c6702f5f3b6e77da6f394e67ef1a6aab.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: AxvhfreM3y8ex1iHfvxuYCPM5RZq4GYfW3mm0OjF5vbI6GSThkYW3g==
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Content Security Policy" should not be an issue. I don't see any Cache-Control/Expire header in the response headers which could cause MISS, it means you need to look at your CloudFront configuration. 
1. Do you have Cache based on Selected header set to ALL ?
2. Do you have any Header whitelisted where value is changing for every request ?
3. All TTL 0 should give you a RefreshHit but check for Cache behavior Configuration if cookies/query strings etc are changing and you have selected Forward ALL set.